# Meaning of "down in the street" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I encountered a question in a paragraph of the novel " Nineteen Eighty-Four ".

https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/o/orwell/george/o79n/chapter1.1.html

The paragraph is below.

> Outside, even through the shut window-pane, the world looked cold. **Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals, and though the sun was shining and the sky a harsh blue, there seemed to be no colour in anything, except the posters that were plastered everywhere.** The black-moustachio’d face gazed down from every commanding corner. There was one on the house-front immediately opposite. BIG BROTHER IS WATCHING YOU, the caption said, while the dark eyes looked deep into Winston’s own. I encountered questions in the sentence " Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals, and though the sun was shining and the sky a harsh blue, there seemed to be no colour in anything, except the posters that were plastered everywhere ".

Does the word "down" mean "along the path of (something)" in the sentence "Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals"?

Why the word "in" is put between "down" and "the street" in the sentence "Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals"?

Comment: Could you please ask one question per question post?  It's okay if you make multiple posts about the same text as long as each contains exactly one question.  Just edit this post to remove every question but one, then post the others separately.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this context the word **down** implies that the writer is above the street at a higher window and looking downwards towards the street.

The word **in** is used as emphasis to indicate that the writer is looking *inside* the street rather than along it. It is used to negate that there is something beyond the street, but that the reference is to something just below and contained within the street and between the buildings.

As you noted, the phrase **down the street** could be used to indicate something at a distance along the path. In this usage it does not.

Comment: I am not very clear about the sentence "but just below contained within the street between the buildings".

Comment: @LiXiaodong I have refined the wording. Does that help?

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩: It can also mean that the writer is North of that described part of the street, or can it? You know - "down south", "up north".

Comment: @InitK - It might, but not in this context.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩: Thanks. It's funny how geography of the place you live in affects how you read/understand things. Here everything is down south, while we are up north :)

Comment: Hello Dear Professor Tompsett, thank you so much for your help again. I really appreciate it. I am still not very clear about it.